# struts 2 jqGrid not getting displayed

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

I have read all followed the example showed in showcase of jqgrid with struts2. But my grid is not getting displayed. Please help me out. Below are my code snippets. When i type the action name in url, it displays me the json. When i type the jsp path in url, It does not display me the jqgrid. But when i view the source of the page, it creates the code for jqgrid.

JSP File

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<%@taglib  prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@taglib  prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond"></sj:head>
</head>
<body>

<s:url id="remoteurl" action="/SreebhogStore/incomingRawMaterial1" />


<sjg:grid id="gridtable" caption="Roles" dataType="json" href="%{remoteurl}" pager="true" gridModel="gridModel"  rowList="10,15,20" rowNum="5" rownumbers="true"
 width="800" navigator="true" navigatorView="false" navigatorDelete="false" 
 navigatorAdd="false" navigatorEdit="false" navigatorSearch="false">
<sjg:gridColumn name="lotNo" index="lotNo" title="Role Name"
 sortable="true" formatter="editrole" />
 </sjg:grid>

</body>
</html>
```

Struts 2 config

```
<package name="incomingRawMaterialManagement" extends="struts-default, json-default"     namespace="/SreebhogStore">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="login" class="com.sreebhog.interceptors.LoginInterceptor" />
<interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
<interceptor-ref name="login" ></interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" ></interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

<action name="incomingRawMaterial1" class="com.sreebhog.actions.IncomingRawMaterialAction">

<result name="success" type="json"></result>

</action> 
</package>
```

And here is my action class

```
public class IncomingRawMaterialAction extends ActionSupport implements LoginRequired,SessionAware,ErrorSuccessMessages
    ,ServletRequestAware{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
HttpServletRequest request;

//For incoming raw material initialization
private List<Products> rawMaterials;
private List<Party> parties;

//For jqGrid
private List<IncomingRawMaterial> gridModel;
private Integer rows = 0; //Number of rows
private Integer page = 0; //Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1.
private String sort;  // sorting order - asc or desc
private String sidx;  // get index row - i.e. user click to sort.
private String searchString;    // The Search String
private String searchOper;  // The Search Operation ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
private Integer total = 0;  // Your Total Pages
private Integer records = 0;    // All Record

public String execute()
{

rows=5;

gridModel = new ArrayList<IncomingRawMaterial>(); 
gridModel.add(new IncomingRawMaterial()); 
gridModel.add(new IncomingRawMaterial()); 
System.out.println("HERE--------------------------------------------------");
//calculate the total pages for the query
total =2;//(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);

return SUCCESS;
}

public String getJSON()
{
System.out.println("JSON------------------------------------------------------");
return execute();
}

//Getters and setters and override methods

//JQGRID GETTERS AND SETTTERS

}
```

Please note that the console messages are also not getting displayed. So I suspect that jqgrid is not calling my action.

Here is the list of jars included
    antlr-2.7.7.jar
    classmate-0.5.4.jar
    commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
    commons-io-1.3.2.jar
    commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    freemarker-2.3.15.jar
    hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
    hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar
    hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
    javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
    jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar
    jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
    jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
    log4j-1.2.14.jar
    mysql-connector-java-5.1.3-rc-bin.jar
    ognl-2.7.3.jar
    servlet-api.jar
    struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
    xwork-core-2.1.6.jar

```
**Here are the important ones i guess.**

struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.5.1.jar
struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
```

**EDIT 1:
I am able to view my grid now but it is still not loading json data. The problem was with formatter attribute in one of sjg:column tag.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590992/struts-2-jqgrid-not-getting-displayed

Comment: Yes. It was I who asked that question. But since i was not getting any replies, I thought of asking the question again. Anywayz, That question has already been removed.

Comment: You don't want to repost the same question twice just because it's not getting attention.  With more reputation, you could attach a bounty to it to garner more looks.  Also, if you've answered the question, feel free to actually answer your question below and accept it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the information. I am actually new to posting here and so didnt know about these things. Will take care of it in future.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:** 
I solved the problem myself. The problem was with s:url tag. It had no namespace defined. I was accessing the link through .../JSP/index.jsp. So it was looking for the action in that /JSP itself. Sorry everyone for the trouble if any. I hope my discovery can help someone in future.